# SQL server for php whit USBWebserver

Tags: php, sql-server, web-services, connection

I have installed the lastest version of sql-server for php. I use a simple USBWebserver and I have pasted all the driver files to the map `C:\php\ext` *(see image below)*. In the file `php\php.ini`, I have place this string behind:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

Here can you see all the files in `C:\php\ext` for running the driver:
[image: files for running the driver]
Whit this I have no errors *(but maybe he didn't throw it)*.

---

Now my problem is when I make my connection to the sql server database. I have the following error:

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined function *sqlsrv_connect()* in c:\root\add.php on line 2

This is my code where I've the exception:

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( array("Database"=>"Immo"), ".\\SQLEXPRESS");
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string that you must place in your `php\php.ini` file is this:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

And for make a connection you must turn the two arguments from place.

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect(".\\SQLEXPRESS", array("Database"=>"Immo"));
```

This has help me to make a connection to a SQL-server with php.